# Convert Days to hours:minutes:second java

Tags: java

How can I convert `0.230324074074074` to `05:31:40` in Java? I have code in sql but need in java.

```
 (select * from(SELECT    TRUNC (
                               (  (X_GSA_LEAVE_SITE - X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE)
                                * 24
                                * 60)
                             / 60)
                       || ':'
                       || (  (  (X_GSA_LEAVE_SITE - X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE)
                              * 24
                              * 60)
                           -   TRUNC (
                                    (  (  X_GSA_LEAVE_SITE
                                        - X_GSA_ARRIVE_ONSITE)
                                     * 24
                                     * 60)
                                  / 60)
                             * 60)
```

Comment: So for clarity, 0.230324074074074 is a fraction of 1 day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun here is an old fashioned `Calendar` version

```
int seconds = (int) (0.230324074074074 * 24 * 60 * 60);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);

String result = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
            cal.get(Calendar.HOUR),
            cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the value `0.230324` is a fraction of a day, and you want to display this as hours:minutes:seconds.  There is a fairly straightforward way to do this in Java 8:

```
double input = 0.230324074074074d;
long seconds = new Double(input*24*60*60).longValue();
System.out.println(LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds(seconds)
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));

05:31:39
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can convert that fraction of day to a `LocalTime` using:

```
LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay((long)(0.230324074074074 * 24 * 60 * 60))
```

This converts the value to seconds and constructs a `LocalTime` object. Printing the result outputs `"05:31:39"` (`LocalTime.toString` outputs time in your desired format). You may need to control rounding in a different way if you expect exactly `05:31:40`)

Answer (score 0):

```
long seconds = (long) (0.230324074074074 * 24 * 60 * 60);
String result = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I took the liberty of changing your first mask so that it would print `05` as per the OP wishes